# Hermite Normal Form and Reduced Row Echelon form.

Tags: matrices, algorithms, euclidean-geometry, hermite-normal-form

After reading about the Hermite Normal form and row echelon form, I find it that both these forms are similar in every respect. My question is, are they similar?
Or is Hermite Normal form a special case of Echelon form. 
If they are similar we can use the same algorithm for finding the row echelon form and Hermite normal form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form) explains the differences and similarities between the two. Finding Hermite normal form for an integer matrix, you're not allowed to divide, so you won't necessarily get a leading 1 in each nonzero row, for instance.